# saving image to parse db without losing quality in android

Tags: android, parse-platform, bitmap, compression

when a user is taking a photo I want to save it to background as a parse file as follows:

```
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

    try {
        stream.flush();
        stream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
       filePic = new ParseFile(userName + ".png", byteArray);

        filePic.saveInBackground();
```

This code works, but the problem is that the image loses its quality even though its set to 100.
Can anyone help with a solution on how to compress the bitmap without losing the quality? or maybe saving it without compressing?

Comment: The quality param is ignored if you use PNG (on another note, why are you adding .jpg in the filename for a png image?) since PNG is lossless so that's not your issue. Your code seems fine and shouldn't add any compression to the image, are you sure Parse doesn't have any kind of built-in compression? (didn't use it before so this is a random guess)

Comment: changed it back to png (got messed up from trying all sorts of ways). ill try to find out if parse is compressing the image in a built-in way.

Comment: Also how did you load your bitmap? Maybe you downsampled it while loading to match your preview (if you have any)?